# ListLinePlot: Options expected (instead of ImportCSVToDataset

Tags: plotting, import, csv-format

I have the following code

```
In[1] data = ImportCSVToDataset["C:\\Users\\Rauriel\\Escritorio\\hola.csv"]
In[2] data[SortBy["POBTOT"], "POBTOT"][Reverse]
In[3] ListLinePlot[data[All, {"NOM_MUN", "POBMAS"}], 
      data[All, {"NOM_NUM", "POBFEM"}]]
```

Error

```
ListLinePlot: Options expected (instead of ImportCSVToDataset[C:\Users\Rauriel\Escritorio\hola.csv][All,{NOM_NUM,POBFEM}]) beyond position 1 in ListLinePlot[ImportCSVToDataset[C:\Users\Rauriel\Escritorio\hola.csv][All,{NOM_MUN,POBMAS}],ImportCSVToDataset[C:\Users\Rauriel\Escritorio\hola.csv][All,{NOM_NUM,POBFEM}]]. An option must be a rule or a list of rules.
```

I don't understand, how do I correct it?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. We need to replicate your scenario in our notebooks so that we can assist you further. In order to do that you have to present a minimal working example. I would request you to load a representative sample of your dataset that recreates your problem. The Mathematica code you load needs to be in a copy-paste-able format (i.e., not an image). Thanks.

Comment: What is the definition of `ImportCSVToDataset`? Looks like it failed to evaluate. You have multiple sets of data, try `ListLinePlot[{data[All, {"NOM_MUN", "POBMAS"}], data[All, {"NOM_NUM", "POBFEM"}]}]` after fixing the import issue.

Comment: I assume that you are trying to use this function from the Wolfram Function Repository: [`ImportCSVToDataset`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ImportCSVToDataset/). If that's correct, then try using `ResourceFunction["ImportCSVToDataset"]["C:\\Users\\Rauriel\\Escritorio\\hola.csv"]` in your code.